# Entity Framework entity integrity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I want to validate each entity when saving. That is, I have some custom C# function in each entity class that validates the data.

How can I do that? I don't want to use database constraints because they cannot express my constraints.

Should I implement some interface???

Comment: What framework are you using, some frameworks allows you to put model constraints in your classes. If you use something like [EF Code-First](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx), then you can write your classes and add validation easily.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277063/best-practise-for-validating-entity-framework-entities-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-a-r/6277207#6277207

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity framework 3.5 and 4.0 offers even called `SavingChanges`. Entity framework 4.0 and 4.1 has `SaveChanges` method virtual (as already mentioned).

You can either override method or use event handler and write code like this for 3.5 and 4.0:

```
var entities = context.ObjectStateManager
                      .GetObjectStateEntries(EntitiState.Modified | EntityState.Added)
                      .Where(e => !e.IsRelationship)
                      .Select(e => e.Entity)
                      .OfType<YourEntityType>();

foreach(var entity in entities)
{
    entity.Validate();
}
```

In DbContext API (EF 4.1) you must use

```
var entities = context.ChangeTracker
                      .Entries<YourEntityType>()
                      .Where(e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
                      .Select(e => e.Entity);

foreach(var entity in entities)
{
    entity.Validate();
}
```

You can use custom interface implemented by your entities which will expose `Validate` method.

Answer (score 4):

The ObjectContext.SaveChanges method is virtual since EF 4.0. Overwrite this method and validate all entities there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395500.aspx

Iterate over all entities (not the deleted ones :)) in the context. Use the ObjectStateManager to gain access to the entities in the context.

Hope this helps and best regards,

http://www.testmaster.ch/EntityFramework.test